# PHP Add Quotes to Comma Separated Terms (PHP/WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to separate two terms joined together into comma separated, quoted values.

With this code:

```
        <?php
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'project_category' );

        if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
            $links = array();

            foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
            {
                $links[] = $term->name;
            }
            $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
            $tax = join(", ", $links);
        else :  
            $tax = '';  
        endif;
        ?>
```

And with this output

```
        <div class="project-item col-sm-3 col-md-3" data-groups='[<?php echo strtolower($tax); ?>]'></div>
```

I am currently getting an array that looks like

```
        <div class="project-item col-sm-3 col-md-3" data-groups='[term1, term2]'>
```

What I'm hoping to get as an array is

```
        <div class="project-item col-sm-3 col-md-3" data-groups='["term1", "term2"]'>
```

This is probably the easiest problem in the world to solve, but I've spent hours pouring over StockOverflow, WordPress forums, and PHP sites and for some reason, cannot figure it out exactly. I've gotten closer and gotten quotes around both terms, but not double quotes, and for the script/plugin to work, it has to be double quotes.

Please help a girl out! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for starters:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
{
    $links[] = '"'.$term->name.'"';
}
```

Comment: HALLELUJAH IT WORKS! Thank you SOOO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best, but a quite simple solution is to just adjust the `$tax` variable before outputting it.

```
$tax = '"'.str_replace(', ','", "',$tax).'"';
```

As long as you don't have any commas followed by spaces in the different "terms" it should work fine.